# Measuring goals for users who have never logged into my site before

Tags: google-analytics

I have a web app. The home page has two main actions:

1. Sign up to the application
2. Log into the application

I have a goal set up for sign-ups. I am trying to track the goal conversion rate of users *who have never logged into the application before*.

The problem I have at the moment is that the conversion rate is being skewed by users who are  visiting the homepage simply to log in.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Thanks very much, 
Ben

Answer (score 0):

For the kind of tracking you are looking for, there should be some coding on both your system and Google Analytics.

First, I would recommend you place into your system the intelligence to know the number of log-ins the user has made (As an example, a counter on your database).

Now, to implement that, you will need to set a Custom Var in Google Analytics in a visit level, to segment the users from the non-users, in that CustomVar, you can store both the user ID and the number of logins he has made.

This is the on the login page:

Your Code Should Look Like:

```
 _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
     1,             
     'Member Login',   
     'NUMBER OF LOGINS', // SET THIS FROM YOUR SYSTEM     
     2 //VISIT LEVEL Custom Var       
  ]);
```

Remember that this code should go before tracking the pageview.

After setting this up, you should use Advanced Segments to check those specific users, one case could be: (Using the example above)

- Setup an Advanced Segment that "Excludes" the Custom Variable (Key 1) - Mathing RegExp : .*

  - This will give you all the never-loged user access.

Something else you could do is set up Adv Segments to check on a specific number of logins

- Setup an Advanced Segment that "Excludes" the Custom Variable (Key 1) - Mathing RegExp : [^1]

  - This will give you all the users that loged-in more than once.

You can find more info on Custom Vars [here](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html).

Comment: I don't see how this helps me to be honest...?

Comment: Using Adv. Segments you can check for exactly the number of users and how the accessed your site and so on that have never loged in your site. Please take a look at the answer again, I have updated it to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for the update. One question though, based on the following scenario. User arrives at site for the first time. Log in count is 0. User signs up, and logs in. Log in count is 1. If I then view stats based on login count = 0, I will miss this newly registered user, no?

Comment: Not at all, all you'll have to do is use the adv. segment based on login count = 1 !

Comment: You won't miss anyone who's loged in your site, no matter how many times they have logged in. In the Custom Var report you will be able to see how many times your users have logged in. With adv. segments all you have to do is either change the val for the CustomVar as mentioned above or create a Regex with a rage you desire to check.